# How to keep the true uniques row?

Tags: r, matrix, row, unique

Here an example of a matrix,

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |

I would like extract only rows which are unique in A and B.
I can't use unique, duplicate etc. because they retain always one of my duplicated row.

In final result I wish obtain:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

How can I do it?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by unique? Can you explain with the other rows are not retained?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of options -

1. Base R -

```
cols <- c('A', 'B')
res <- df[!(duplicated(df[cols]) | duplicated(df[cols], fromLast = TRUE)), ]
res

#  A B C
#3 1 2 4
#4 2 1 1
```

2. `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(A, B) %>% filter(n() == 1) %>% ungroup

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#      A     B     C
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     4
#2     2     1     1
```

Comment: Oh, wow, I did not understand the question like that but that makes more sense ahah. Let's see what OP thinks!

Comment: Perfect the three solution worked, even if with the dplyr I have a duplication of the A and B column. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**data.table**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
  B = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
  C = c(1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L)
)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N == 1], by = list(A, B)]
#>    A B C
#> 1: 1 2 4
#> 2: 2 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>